# Change input text color on dark or light mode

Tags: css

I create a dark/light theme switcher and the problem that I discover is when I enter any information in input field while the website in dark mode, the text inside input field appears black, how I can change it to keep black text colour on light mode and white text colour on dark mode.

Here is my CSS for light/dark mode. How I can add a different text color for dark mode?

```
:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(82, 80, 144);
    --secondary-color: #536390;
    --font-color: #424242;
    --bg-color: #fff;
    --heading-color: #292922;
    --color: black;
  }
  [data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: rgb(107, 106, 134);
    --secondary-color: #818cab;
    --font-color: #e1e1ff;
    --bg-color: #4d5055;
    --heading-color: #63656d;
    --color: white; 
  }
  body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--font-color);
  }
  h1 {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
  }

  a{
    color: var(--primary-color);
  }
input {
color: var(--color);
}
```

HTML part

```
<div class="input-field" data-theme="dark">
<input type="text" id="searchquery" placeholder="Type here">
</div>
```

I was trying to it with this code, but it changes for both dark and light mode.

```
input, select, textarea{
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

EDITED: I add the content from answer below. It works now with only one problem, when I change to the light mode the input text color remains white, but suppose to be black color.

Comment: You could use this: `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { }` to change the colour just for dark mode. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: As I understand right the code suppose to look like that `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { 
  .input-field{
    color: white;
  }
}`
But currently it doesn't work for me, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to add the attribute `data-theme="dark"` in the labels or any parent for it take effect. I hope this can help you.

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(82, 80, 144);
    --secondary-color: #536390;
    --font-color: #424242;
    --bg-color: #fff;
    --heading-color: #292922;
    --color: black;
  }
  [data-theme="dark"] {
    --primary-color: rgb(107, 106, 134);
    --secondary-color: #818cab;
    --font-color: #e1e1ff;
    --bg-color: #4d5055;
    --heading-color: #63656d;
    --color: red; 
  }
  body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--font-color);
  }
  h1 {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
  }

  a{
    color: var(--primary-color);
  }

input {
    color: var(--color);
  }
```

```html
<h1 data-theme="dark">Input with data-theme attribute "dark"</h1>
<div class="input-field" data-theme="dark">
    <input type="text" id="searchquery" placeholder="Type here">
</div>

<h1>Input wihout data-theme attribute "dark"</h1>
<div class="input-field">
    <input type="text" id="searchquery" placeholder="Type here">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, yes it works for me, the only thing that the input text color stays white even in light mode.